# "Error: Items not allowed (keepout area..)" KiCAD

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, via, tracking

[image]

I have got this erorr. What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have placed vias and tracks within a keepout area, i.e. an area where specific features are not allowed. Keepout areas are polygons that can be set to prevent the placement of any combination of footprints, vias, tracks, pads, or copper fill within their borders.

Keepout areas are either part of footprints, or placed manually by you using the keepout area tool:

[image: Arrow pointing to keepout area icon in KiCAD 7.]

You'll need to review your design, see where the error arrows are pointing, and ultimately either reroute your traces or reconfigure/remove the keepout area. If the keepout area is a part of a footprint that you sourced from somewhere else, check the datasheet for the component and ensure that you are, in fact, allowed to run traces or vias through that area.

Comment: Notice that the keepout can also be edited.

Comment: @MiNiMe If it's a board-level keepout. If it's a footprint level keepout, it can only be edited by editing the footprint.

Comment: True. In this case the evidence strongly points to a keepout zone though. And I see Matt already addressed what I commented: "reconfigure/remove the keepout area"

Comment: I did, thanks to your comment. I appreciate you for pointing it out, @MiNiMe!